# SignaIR - C# - Resposta em Tempo Real

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, websocket, signalr

Estou usando C#, Asp .Net, SQL Server.

Tenho a seguinte dúvida, estou criando uma aplicação web e mobile para se comunicar com um WebApi porém me deparei com o problema de informações e/ou dados em real-time, através de pesquisas encontrei o signalr, até ai tudo bem, criando o o projeto signalr é bem simples e tal, agora como faço para hospedá-lo?
-Tenho que por em um servidor próprio?
-Se sim, alguém conhece máquinas virtuais baratas (que não sejam Azure e Google Cloud pois são caras demais para mim lançar um produto novo no mercado)?

Procurei em vários lugares mas não encontrei nada referente a minha dúvida.

Comment: Olá Ricardo, bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português, a sua pergunta é muito ampla e as possíveis respostas são baseadas em opinião pessoal. Ela provavelmente será fechada por algum moderador, então recomendo que você dê uma lida no [Tour do site](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender sobre o funcionamento do site. E sobre hospedagem barata, bom, dê uma olhada [nessa página no site oficial do ASP.NET](http://hosting.asp.net/hosting/home), vai te ajudar a encontrar alguma coisa.

Comment: Poderia arrumar a pergunta? gostaria muito de responder, em resumo o SignalR já esta incorporado no source do WebApi (4.1 adiante), ou seja, é como se fosse um projeto normal de WebAPI e pode hospedar em um servidor IIS qualquer, lembrando que por ser realtime, talvez a banda de consumo seja um pouco maior e na parte de processamento depende doque for utilizar. Voce pode criar um projeto que tenha os 2 tipos (WebAPI e SignalR) juntos, pode integrar chamadas entre eles tb! Link para possiveis duvidas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368800/can-i-incorporate-both-signalr-and-a-restful-api

Comment: Um detalhe importante, não crie um projeto 100% signalR, mescle a necessidade do realtime e o não realtime com o WebAPI. Nem tudo precisa ser realtime, até mesmo em um jogo!